# My page keeps changing how it looks when I change window size

Tags: html, css, responsive

Let me first point out that I am new to HTML. I'm in high school and I'm currently making a website for my portfolio. Here's the problem, I can't get my page to be responsive. I have tried the stuff that was on the internet but they didn't seem to work. Here is my website- http://danil1.gitastudent.online/

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Quicksand&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
      <style>
          body {
              font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
               font-size:25px;
              overflow-x:hidden;
          }
          
          .container {
            position:absolute;
            width:100%;
            
          }
          
          .zoom {
            padding: 10px;
            transition: transform .2s;
            margin: 0 auto;
          }
            
          .textG {
            left:730px;
            top:250px;
            transition-property: left;
            transition-duration: 0.15s;
            transition-timing-function: linear;
            position:relative;
            z-index:-1;
          }
          .textI {
            left:1180px;
            top:250px;
            transition-property: left;
            transition-duration: 0.15s;
            transition-timing-function: linear;
            position:relative;
            z-index:-1;
          }
          .textT {
            left:730px;
            top:750px;
            transition-property: left;
            transition-duration: 0.15s;
            transition-timing-function: linear;
            position:relative;
            z-index:-1;
          }
          .textA {
            left:1180px;
            top:750px;
            transition-property: left;
            transition-duration: 0.15s;
            transition-timing-function: linear;
            position:relative;
            z-index:-1;
          }
          
          .container:hover .textG{
            left:850px;
          }
          .container:hover .textI{
            left:1340px;
          }
          .container:hover .textT{
            left:830px;
          }
          .container:hover .textA{
            left:1400px;
          }
          .zoom:hover {
            transform: scale(1.02); 
      </style>
  </head>
    <body>
      <div style="position:relative; left:30; top:30; font-size:30px;"><b>GITA.</b></div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="zoom">
          <img src="G.png" id="g" width="40%" style="position:absolute; left:300; top:10;">
        </div>
          <div class="textG">
            <div><b>ABOUT</b></div>
          </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="container">
        <div class="zoom">
          <img src="I.png" id="i" width="40%" style="position:absolute; left:850; top:10;">
        </div>
          <div class="textI">
            <div><b>WORKS</b></div>
          </div>
      </div>
     
      <div class="container">
        <div class="zoom">
          <img src="T.png" id="t" width="40%" style="position:absolute; left:300; top:450;">
        </div>
          <div class="textT">
            <div><b>GITA</b></div>
          </div>
      </div>
     
      <div class="container">
        <div class="zoom">
          <img src="A.png" id="a" width="40%" style="position:absolute; left:850; top:450;">
        </div>
          <div class="textA">
              <div><b>CONTACT</b></div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'd advise against using position absolute to establish your layout. It's going to make it much, much harder to manage placement of elements and adapt to different viewport sizes because you're going against the browser's natural flow. Look at [css grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) and [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex).

Comment: You are using absolute positions in combination with pixel sizes and pixel positions. Something like that cannot be responsive. Use relative measurement unit and media queries.

Answer (score 0):

For each screen size you can use:

```
 @media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
      #your Code...
    }
```

or

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
          #your Code...
        }
```

For more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my original comment, I'd strongly advise against using CSS position to establish layout. You'll find yourself in a cat-herding situation as content changes and as you're trying to adapt to different viewport sizes.

The snippet below does not faithfully recreate every aspect of your existing page, but it demonstrates a much simpler approach using less markup and less css that will be much easier to manage and make responsive.

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;  /* prevent images from being larger than their container */
}

.big-nav {
  list-style: none; /* get rid of default list styling */
  padding: 0; /* get rid of default list margin */
  margin: 0; /* get rid of default list padding */
  
  max-width: 1024px; /* limit max width */
  margin: 0 auto; /* center in the page */
  
  display: grid; /* use a grid layout */
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; /* two equally sized columns */
  gap: 1rem; /* space between the grid cells */
}

.big-nav > * {
  border: 1px dashed lightblue; /* so you can see the grid */
}
```

```html
<!-- set base href so your images will load -->
<base href="http://danil1.gitastudent.online/"/>

<div>
    <div><b>GITA.</b></div>
    <ul class="big-nav">
        <li>
            <img src="G.png">
            <div class="label">ABOUT</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="I.png">
            <div class="label">WORKS</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="T.png">
            <div class="label">GITA</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="A.png">
            <div class="label">CONTACT</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: although the code you gave me was centered in 720p, the code was more at the top of the page on 1080p

Comment: How to vertically center an element is a question that’s been asked and answered a million times. Search SO and you’ll find it.